# remote asp udp protocol

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

I'm using AxInterop.MSTSCLib.dll in my app to remote to my server
the code is common like below:

```
var rdp = new AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting();
rdp.Server = "ServerAddress";
rdp.UserName = "Username";
sec.ClearTextPassword = "password";
rdp.Connect();
```

now i want to remote as UDP protocol
the server pc is ready for udp remote(udp components installed) and i tested it by Remote Desktop
but what i do in my app and code to remote to server as UDP enabled?

Answer (score 0):

depending on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387299/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-connection-programmatically) , you need to use this code to enable the remote desktop if i understand you well this code what you need

```
try
        {
            RegistryKey key = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, TargetMachine.Name);
            key = key.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server", true);
            object val = key.GetValue("fDenyTSConnections");
            bool state = (int)val != 0;
            if (state)
            {
                key.SetValue("fDenyTSConnections", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                MessageBox.Show("Remote Desktop is now ENABLED");
            }
            else
            {
                key.SetValue("fDenyTSConnections", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                MessageBox.Show("Remote Desktop is now DISABLED");
            }
            key.Flush();
            if (key != null)
                key.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error toggling Remote Desktop permissions");
        }
```

Comment: i had good connection as tcp protocol and remote is enabled,now i need remote as udp protocol